# Imprimir campo enum no JasperReports

Tags: java, jasper-reports, enums, jasper

Eu criei um `Enum` que possui um campo de descrição para cada um de seus itens.

No meu relatório no `Jaspersoft Studio` eu quero imprimir este campo de descrição e não o `name()` do `Enum`.

Eu criei um field no relatório, mas ao selecionar o tipo da classe não aparece o meu `Enum` daí não tem como selecionar o `.getDescricao()`.

```
public enum Direcao {

    ENTRADA("Entrada"),
    SAIDA("Saída");

    private final String descricao;

    Direcao(String descricao) {
        this.descricao = descricao;
    }

    public String getDescricao() {
        return descricao;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui resolver, dá para forçar o tipo do `field` na declaração dele no `.jrxml` e apartir disso vai ter acesso aos métodos do `Enum`.

```
<field name="tipo" class="br.com.empresa.sistema.entity.Direcao"/>
```